# What is procedure for computing effective masses from these three quantities?

Tags: mass, quantum-transport

Given a reciprocal effective mass tensor in a principle basis

$\left[M_E\right]^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1/m_l&0&0\\0&1/m_t&0\\0&0&1/m_t\end{bmatrix}$

You can compute the reciprocal effective mass tensor in the device coordinate basis vectors by the transformation

$[M_D]^{-1} = T^T[M_E]^{-1}T$

But I am not sure what the transformation matrix should be. Normally two pieces of information are given: The device orientation (e.g.) [100] and the substrate/wafer orientation [010]. Can a transformation matrix be derived from these two quantities?

In summary, my question: Given i) a reciprocal effective mass tensor in a principle axis basis ii) a wafer orientation and iii) a device orientation, is there a general procedure for computing the reciprocal effective mass tensor in the device basis?